# Connection between pages

Tags: site, content-and-structure

I have a documentlibrary and a few questions about childsite to childsite, parentsite to childsite & childsiteto parentsitestructure. 
Consider a documentlibrary that's on the parentpage and is filled with documents.
I want to display that same documentlibrary on the childpage with those same documents.
How do I accomplish this? And when I have a documentlibrary on different childpages
how can I display those on the parentpage?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just for clarification: when you say "parent-page" you actually mean "page on parent site"? ..and what you try to achieve is to have a view of documents from a child-site on the parent Site. I assume all in the same Site Collection??

Comment: I mean, a subsite with subsite under 1 subsite. You know, like a tree strucute. Subsite A has x Subsites under it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many ways, however with some constraints, and even require development.

Simple scenarios:

1. Use CQWP (Content Query Web Part) is the most simple to use - it
   does however require Publishing Sites (or to activate Publishing
   infrastructure). This allows for rollup of content across the whole
   site collection, including targeting a particular list at some
   sub-site level.
2. Use DVWP (Data View Web Part) - many ways to achieve it, mostly via SPD, but have a look here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/cb8717b9-21fb-4f86-9489-93f478ecaf44 for a step by step example, or here http://blog.concurrency.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-cross-site-content-rollup-using-sharepoint-designer-2010-and-a-dataview-web-part/
3. Customize a Search Core Results web part with a particular scope - less for targeting one list, works across site collection, but requires certain know-how.

More complex (aka Programatic) - even requiring custom Web parts that rely on rollup/agregation techniques (start here http://www.codeguru.com/whitepapers/article.php/c16999/Building-a-Rollup-List-in-SharePoint.htm). Use any of the ways mentioned here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649417.aspx) which rely on SPSiteDataQuery (what CQPW uses also), PortalSiteMapProvider or other technique

Comment: Happy I could help, that is why we are here! Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

If you are sharing the same content between them why not simply create one site, and create multiple pages within that?